# Reloading of persisted entity

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

I'm using OpenJPA in my application as a JPA vendor.

The question is theoretical or conceptual:

Is there any way to tell an entity manager to load an entity from the DB rather than from it's cache?

The problematic scenario:

```
EM1.persist(Entity1)
EM2.merge(Entity1)
EM1.find(Entity1)  <--- Entity1 is the cached version rather than the merged one..
```

Any elegant way to do it? I really don't want to call `em.refresh(entity)`.

Comment: What's wrong with `em.refresh(entity)`? It's just one line of code, any other solution is not going to be any more terse than that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the entity available then em.refresh(entity) is the cleanest way to force the entity to be reloaded.

If you don't have the entity available you can call:

```
EM1.clear(); // all entities are detached - might not be desired.  
EM1.find(Entity1);
```

In JPA 2.0 you could also explicitly detach the entity (but I don't see this as being better than em.refresh()):

```
EM1.detach(Entity); 
EM1.find(Entity1);
```